# How to invalidate cloudfront s3 bucket with a wildcard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

The documentation shows how to invalidate specific items:

```
{
  "Paths": {
    "Quantity": 2,
    "Items": ["/index.html", "/error.html"]
  },
  "CallerReference": "my-invalidation-2015-09-01"
}
```

However, as part of my build, I'd like to invalidate *everything*. Somehting like this:

```
{
  "Paths": {
    "Items": "/*"
  },
  "CallerReference": "my-invalidation-2015-09-01"
}
```

Is there a way to do that with the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this works:

```
{
  "Paths" : {
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Items": ["/*"]
  }, 
  "CallerReference": "whatever"
}
```

I wonder if get charged for invalidating just one item :-)...
Probably not... and I'll probably pay a lot for invalidating all of my site's static resources every time.

Comment: Actually, [Amazon claims](https://aws.amazon.com/de/about-aws/whats-new/2015/05/amazon-cloudfront-makes-it-easier-to-invalidate-multiple-objects/) you only pay for one invalidation in this case.